# Confused by setuptools "name" keyword parameter using Click module

Tags: python, setuptools, python-click

I'm confused by the Setuptools *keyword parameter* `name` given in the Click module examples.

I didn't find any explicit reference to `name` keyword parameter in the [Setuptools Documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html). The first mention under [Basic Use](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use) gives no account, and only [New and Changed keywords](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) are detailed.

[Dynamic Discovery of Services and Plugins](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) describes the Entry Points syntax, but only provides these relational definitions:

> The entry_points argument to `setup()` accepts either a string with .ini-style sections, or a dictionary mapping entry point group names
>   to either strings or lists of strings containing entry point
>   specifiers. An entry point specifier consists of a name and value,
>   separated by an = sign. The value consists of a **dotted module name**,
>   optionally followed by a : and a **dotted identifier naming an object**
>   **within the module**.  [My emphasis]

This description makes no reference to the `name` keyword parameter--are they unconnected?

The first example in the [Click Docs](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/#setuptools-integration) makes `name` appear to be the **module name** (where 'module' is just your single `.py` file, ie. `yourscript.py`),

```
setup(
    name='yourscript',
    [...stuff...]
    py_modules=['yourscript'],
    [...]
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        yourscript=yourscript:cli
    ''',
```

The second example's naming suggests name is the **package name** (ie. the parent directory for your 'module', where module is a host of files).

```
setup(
    name='yourpackage',
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        yourscript=yourpackage.scripts.yourscript:cli
    ''',
)
```

There are really two "name" arguments I'm unsure about

- Setup keyword parameter `name` and,
- Entry Point name

  - `[name??] = [dotted module name]:[module object name]`).

I don't understand if these arguments relate to elements in your code, or only exist in the `setup.py` (and related pip files). And, does the Entry Point value refer to the Setup value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setup(name='…')` names your **package**. I.e. if you create a source or binary package  with `python setup.py sdist` or `python setup.py bdist_egg` or `python setup.py bdist_wheel` you will have `$name-$version.tar.gz` or `$name-$version.egg` `$name-$version.whl` files. If you upload the files using `twine upload` they will be uploaded to `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/$name/$version`.

The **package name** often is the same as the name of the directory with code and almost always is the same as the **module name**, but it's not required. I have a package [Cheetah3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cheetah3), but its module name is [Cheetah](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/tree/master/Cheetah).

Unlike the **package name** `entry_points` are related to your code. They are executable entries inside your code. As they're executed at runtime, they, of course, contain the name of the **module**. They have nothing with **package**.

See the example:

```
/yourpackage/ <- this is the top-level directory; can be any
                 not necessary the same as package or module
    /yourmodule/ <- this is the top-level module directory;
                    it's what you use in `import yourmodule`
    /setup.py
```

Comment: Do you know what the entry_point name (`[name??] = [dotted module name]:[module object name]`) refers to in the Click context?

Comment: It's a name of a script (entry points are executable scripts). Could be any, especially when there are multiple entry points.