# how to specify the name of a package?

Tags: python-packaging

I have built and installed via pip a python package, let's say `tetris`. Now, on a another branch I have written code that adds some new functionality to the master branch, lets call that branch `tetris_3D`.
I want to build and install on my local pc a package from the `tetris_3D` branch and give it a name `tetris_3D`. I would like both packages `tetris` and `tetris_3D` to co-exist on my machine.

How can I do that?

I thought that changing the name in the `setup.py` file would work. However something like:

```
setup(
    name="tetris_3D",
    license="BSD",
    ...
    ...
```

doesnt seem to help. The whl is getting created, the package is installed but I cannot import it. My `Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` folder has both `tetris_3D.dist.info` and `tetris` folders but it looks to me that the 3D code has overwritten everything inside `tetris` instead of creating a new fresh one.
When I do `import tetris` then it is the 3D code that gets imported.

Comment: Changing the name of the *distribution* package doesn't change the name of the *Python* package it provides.

Comment: Distinguish **distribution** package and **import** package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836860/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758